# Can we store session in Database?

Tags: node.js

Can we store session in database Mysql not in memory using passport module.

**I am using nodejs, express and mysql**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passport module doesn't provide sessions to your application, it uses `connect` or `express` session.

`connect`/`express` sessions may (and should!) be persistent and there are plenty of session stores available on `npm`.

With a quick search I found two implementations of `connect`/`express` mysql session store:

- [connect-mysql](https://github.com/nlf/connect-mysql)
- [express-mysql-session](https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session)

Just take any one of them and use as your session store with `express-session` (or `conncect.session`):

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var SessionStore = require('express-mysql-session')

var app = express();
var sessionStore = new SessionStore(/*options*/);

app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
```